# File upload of more than 10000 records into SQL Server with WCF service

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, performance, wcf

I am using a WCF Service with an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. I have an interface where user can upload a CSV file that contains more than 100000 records. I am uploading this file to the server and in the data layer I am processing these 100000 records one by one and saving them into database.

The WCF client service will invoke this database call in the data access layer and once the saving is done, the WCF service will return success message to the controller.

This works fine but it takes more than 20 minutes to process around 100000 records.

Can someone advice me what will be the best possible solution to finish this process in lesser time.

Thanks
Tarak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than individual `INSERT` statements, consider inserting all rows at once using [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy) or a [table-valued parameter](http://www.dbdelta.com/maximizing-performance-with-table-valued-parameters/) (TVP). This will eliminate the latency of separate calls and synchronous commits for each, out-performing traditional inserts by orders of magnitude.